# Is $\{ t^{2n} \vert n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ complete in$ L^2[0,1]$? And in $L^2[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is $A = \{ t^{2n} \vert n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ complete in $L^2[0,1]$? And in $L^2[-1,1]$?

I managed to prove, using stone weierstrass theorem, that it A is indeed complete in $L^2[0,1]$. I think that A is not complete in $L^2[-1,1]$ because in my proof I used also the fact that functions in A are bijective in [0,1], but this part is not true for [-1,1].

However I can't seem to find a function in $L^2[-1,1]$ such that there doesn't exist a sequence of functions in A that converges to it.

Any hint?

Comment: The linear span of $A$ consists of *even* functions only.

Comment: I see. Easier than I imagined.

Comment: Can you find a sequence of functions converging to the polynomial $x$? Use the fact that a sequence of uniformly converging polynomials converges pointwise, and the fact that the span of $A$ consists of even functions. The other part is correct, and one may even find the answer via a modification of the Bernstein polynomial, or using the gram matrix and Cauchy's determinant formula.

Comment: $\langle x,t^{2n}\rangle_{L^2[-1,1]} =0$ for all $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. So $A$ is not complete in $L^2[-1,1]$.